# How to display two separate sum from two different tables in single SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables; one shows all the event and the users who were invited to the event and their RSVP status.  You can see the code I created at [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/506ad/5)

```
CREATE TABLE EventInvitation(
  InvitedUserId INT,
  EventId INT,
  IsAccepted BIT
)

INSERT INTO EventInvitation VALUES (1,1,1)
INSERT INTO EventInvitation VALUES (2,1,1)
INSERT INTO EventInvitation VALUES (1,2,1)
INSERT INTO EventInvitation VALUES (1,3,0)
INSERT INTO EventInvitation VALUES (2,3,1)
INSERT INTO EventInvitation VALUES (3,3,0)

CREATE TABLE EventRSVPComment(
  EventId INT,
  Comment VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO EventRSVPComment VALUES (1,'comment1_1')
INSERT INTO EventRSVPComment VALUES (1,'comment1_2')
INSERT INTO EventRSVPComment VALUES (1,'comment1_3')
INSERT INTO EventRSVPComment VALUES (2,'comment2_1')
INSERT INTO EventRSVPComment VALUES (2,'comment2_2')
INSERT INTO EventRSVPComment VALUES (2,'comment2_3')
INSERT INTO EventRSVPComment VALUES (3,'comment3_1')
INSERT INTO EventRSVPComment VALUES (3,'comment3_2')
```

[image]

The next table is the event comments:

[image]

I need to write a query to show each event with its total invites, total accepted and total comments like the table below:

[image]

So far I was able to display the invite & accepted using the query below, I could not get the total comment to show up correctly yet.

```
SELECT 
  EI.EventId,
  COUNT(*) AS Invited,
  SUM(CASE WHEN EI.IsAccepted = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Accepted
FROM EventInvitation EI
GROUP BY EI.EventId
```

[image]

I have tried to fiddle with left join, inner join etc. without luck, I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Please do not post images of data or code, please paste in as text

Comment: hi Charlie, I put the code in the sqlfiddle link, I thought putting the image here will help visualize the context of my question.

Comment: It's good to have a fiddle, but please also put the schema in the question. Images are unreadable for many, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post or just paste the whole `CREATE TABLE...INSERT` in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case the easiest is to just use a correlated subquery

```sql
SELECT 
  EI.EventId,
  COUNT(*) AS Invited,
  SUM(CASE WHEN EI.IsAccepted = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Accepted,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EventRSVPComment c WHERE c.EventId = EI.EventId) AS TotalComments
FROM EventInvitation EI
GROUP BY EI.EventId
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/506ad/14)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `inner join` to join with a dataset of *TotalComments* per event :

```
SELECT EI.EventId, COUNT(*) AS Invited,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN EI.IsAccepted = 1 THEN 1 END) AS Accepted,
       MAX(totalComments) as totalComments
FROM EventInvitation EI
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT EventId, count(1) AS totalComments
  FROM EventRSVPComment
  GROUP BY EventId
) as s ON s.EventId = EI.EventId
GROUP BY EI.EventId;
```

[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/506ad/25)

Comment: @Fylix Slight difference between this answer and mine: this answer only gives results if there are any Comment rows (because of the inner-join rather than a left-join), so it depends what result you want